# Deserialize array of object using jms/serializer

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I want to deserialize something like this:

```
[
    { "id": 42 },
    { "id": 43 }
]
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I read all the documentation and did not find any this for this... The only solution I found is to create an other class a do something like this: `@Type("array<Class>")` but it does not work since the array should have a key to work

Comment: So if it doesn't belong to an entity, its just json - so what is wrong with using php's json_decode?

Comment: The goal of using jms/serializer is to transforme json string into your objects, not stdClass like when using json_decode

Comment: `$serializer->deserialize($json, 'array<T>', 'json');` ? Where `T` is the type with `id` property.

Comment: Almost, but thanks ! It work with `deserialize($json, "array<Class>")` you can post the answer if you want.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It would be

```
$serializer->deserialize($json, 'array<T>', 'json')
```

where `T` is the name of the class with the `id` property.

Comment: Is there a way to preserve keys (ex: `[123=> { "id": 42 }, 234=>{ "id": 42 }]` ) within the array? This worked for me but the keys are reset (starting from 0)

Comment: Figured it out:
`$this->serializer->deserialize($result, 'array<integer,MyModelDefinedInYML>>', 'json')`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a class foo, that has an attribute with an array of bar objects.

In your foo class use `JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type as Type;` and annotate the attribute like this:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type as Type;
class foo {
    /**
     *
     * @Type("array<int,Namespace\To\Class\Bar>")
     * private $bars = array();
     */
 }
```

JMS Serializer will serialize/deserialize the contents of foo automagically.  This use of @Type should be utilized for all attributes of any classes you will be serializing/deserializing.

This also works in situations where you are using string keys (ie. associative array structure).  Just substitute "string" for int.

```
@Type("array<string,Namespace\To\Class\Bar>")
```