# jms / fos paramconverter - deserialize multiple objects from single payload

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jms-serializer

i'd like to use the fos / jms bodyconverter in symfony to deserialize two objects from one request payload:

```
{ "object_data_1": ..., "object_data_2" : ...}
```

and then capture like so:

```
#[ParamConverter('obj1', options: ['configure starting node here?'], converter: 'fos_rest.request_body')]
#[ParamConverter('obj2', options: ['configure starting node here?'], converter: 'fos_rest.request_body')]
public function controllerMethod(Obj1 $obj1, Obj2 $obj2) : Response
{...}
```

i cant find any documentation regarding this. does anyone know if this is possible, or if there is any smart way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize array of object using jms/serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482033/deserialize-array-of-object-using-jms-serializer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482033/deserialize-array-of-object-using-jms-serializer?rq=2

Comment: Thyx @Robidu but i have two different kinds of objects